# Copying Files from \data\data to External memory

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to copy some files from a directory in \data\data*\cache\ to a folder in the External Memory. I have root access, and have chmod 777 the applications folder, so have access to these files but when trying to copy these files either with Apache IO or Input/Output stream I get either "file does not exist" or "Can't access this directory".

Here is my Asynctask with Apache and my logcat. Any help would be great, thanks.

```
private class CopyandList extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void>{

    ProgressDialog SnapDialog= new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        SnapDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        SnapDialog.setTitle("Copying...");
        SnapDialog.setMessage("Please Wait");
        SnapDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        SnapDialog.setCancelable(false);
        SnapDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        File file = new File(directory);
        File list[] = file.listFiles();

        for( int i=0; i< list.length; i++){ 
            File X = new File(directory + list[i].getAbsolutePath());
            File Y = new File(destination.getAbsolutePath());
            try {
                FileUtils.copyFileToDirectory(X, Y, true);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        if(SnapDialog.isShowing()){
            SnapDialog.dismiss();
        }
        File file;
        file = new File(Snapdes);
        File list[] = file.listFiles();
        ListView ListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.SnapList); 
        List<String> SnapList;
        SnapList = new ArrayList<String>();
        for( int i=0; i< list.length; i++){
            SnapList.add( list[i].getName() );
        }
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String> (MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, SnapList);
        ListView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

---

```
05-31 15:23:47.060: W/System.err(19176): java.io.FileNotFoundException: Source '/data/data/com.snapchat.android/cache/received_image_snaps/data/data/com.snapchat.android/cache/received_image_snaps/h1a81hurcs00h1370007662341.jpg.nomedia' does not exist
05-31 15:23:47.060: W/System.err(19176):    at     org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyFile(FileUtils.java:1074)
05-31 15:23:47.060: W/System.err(19176):    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyFileToDirectory(FileUtils.java:1013)
05-31 15:23:47.060: W/System.err(19176):    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyFileToDirectory(FileUtils.java:977)
05-31 15:23:47.060: W/System.err(19176):    at com.itsallwhite.sneakysnapper.MainActivity$CopyandList.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:152)
05-31 15:23:47.060: W/System.err(19176):    at com.itsallwhite.sneakysnapper.MainActivity$CopyandList.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
05-31 15:23:47.060: W/System.err(19176):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
05-31 15:23:47.060: W/System.err(19176):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
05-31 15:23:47.060: W/System.err(19176):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
05-31 15:23:47.060: W/System.err(19176):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
05-31 15:23:47.060: W/System.err(19176):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
05-31 15:23:47.060: W/System.err(19176):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
05-31 15:23:47.060: W/System.err(19176): java.io.FileNotFoundException: Source '/data/data/com.snapchat.android/cache/received_image_snaps/data/data/com.snapchat.android/cache/received_image_snaps/h1a81hurcs00h1370007662458.jpg.nomedia' does not exist
05-31 15:23:47.060: W/System.err(19176):    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyFile(FileUtils.java:1074)
05-31 15:23:47.065: W/System.err(19176):    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyFileToDirectory(FileUtils.java:1013)
05-31 15:23:47.065: W/System.err(19176):    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyFileToDirectory(FileUtils.java:977)
05-31 15:23:47.065: W/System.err(19176):    at com.itsallwhite.sneakysnapper.MainActivity$CopyandList.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:152)
05-31 15:23:47.065: W/System.err(19176):    at com.itsallwhite.sneakysnapper.MainActivity$CopyandList.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
05-31 15:23:47.065: W/System.err(19176):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
05-31 15:23:47.065: W/System.err(19176):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
05-31 15:23:47.075: W/System.err(19176):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
05-31 15:23:47.075: W/System.err(19176):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
05-31 15:23:47.075: W/System.err(19176):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
05-31 15:23:47.075: W/System.err(19176):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
05-31 15:23:47.075: W/System.err(19176): java.io.FileNotFoundException: Source '/data/data/com.snapchat.android/cache/received_image_snaps/data/data/com.snapchat.android/cache/received_image_snaps/h1a81hurcs00h1370007662469.jpg.nomedia' does not exist
05-31 15:23:47.075: W/System.err(19176):    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyFile(FileUtils.java:1074)
05-31 15:23:47.080: W/System.err(19176):    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyFileToDirectory(FileUtils.java:1013)
05-31 15:23:47.080: W/System.err(19176):    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyFileToDirectory(FileUtils.java:977)
05-31 15:23:47.080: W/System.err(19176):    at com.itsallwhite.sneakysnapper.MainActivity$CopyandList.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:152)
05-31 15:23:47.080: W/System.err(19176):    at com.itsallwhite.sneakysnapper.MainActivity$CopyandList.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
05-31 15:23:47.080: W/System.err(19176):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
05-31 15:23:47.080: W/System.err(19176):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
05-31 15:23:47.080: W/System.err(19176):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
05-31 15:23:47.080: W/System.err(19176):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
05-31 15:23:47.080: W/System.err(19176):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
05-31 15:23:47.080: W/System.err(19176):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Comment: try with Process root = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");

Comment: Perhaps you did not apply the permission change recursively.  But changing permissions on a data folder (especially when you grant write access) is unwise anyway.  It might be better to use shell commands to do the copying as root; at least that way you limit the changes.

Comment: I used RootTools to check if root is available and then used it to send the commands "su" and then "chmod 777 data/data/..." I shall try shell commands to copy the files and see if I can get it to work. Thanks